Why "HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error" happened after I clicked the Update button?
This error happens when I tried to edit the profile in the JSP work.
Error Message
The error shown below in NetBeans:
|#]
  org.apache.catalina.util.Enumerator@3b90e68c|#]
  StandardWrapperValve[UpdateProfileServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet UpdateProfileServlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ict.db.AccountDB.updateUser(AccountDB.java:178)
    at servlet.UpdateProfileServlet.doPost(UpdateProfileServlet.java:58)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
|#]

Here is the link of the source code because the full code is very long, and here is the
Source Code
[User_Profile.jsp]
<%-- 
    Document   : Profie
    Created on : 2024年4月12日, 上午12:51:25
    Author     : User
--%>


<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.HttpSession"%>
<%@ page import="ict.Bean.AccountBean"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="true"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        //<style> ... </style>
        <script>
            function showContact() {
                var contactInfo = document.getElementById("contact-info");
                contactInfo.classList.toggle("hidden");
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <%

            AccountBean user = (AccountBean) session.getAttribute("AccountBean");
            if (user == null) {
                response.sendRedirect("LoginUser.jsp"); // Redirect to login if no session found
                return;
            }
        %>
        
        <form method="POST" action="UpdateProfileServlet">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row gutters">
                    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="account-settings">
                                    <div class="user-profile">                                       
                                        <input type="text" name="id"  value="<%= user.getId()%>" hidden>
                                        <h5 class="user-name"><%= user.getUsername()%></h5>
                                        <h6 class="user-email"><%=user.getEmail()%></h6>
                                        <h6 class="user-role"><%= user.getRole()%></h6>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-9 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                        <div class="card h-100">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row gutters">
                                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                        <h6 class="mb-2 text-primary">Personal Details</h6>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="fullName">Full Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fullName" name="name" placeholder="Enter full name" value="<%= user.getUsername()%>">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="eMail">Email</label>
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="eMail" name="email" value="<%= user.getEmail()%>" placeholder="Enter email">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                                        <div class="form-group"> 
                                            <label for="role">Role</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Role" value="<%=user.getRole()%>" readonly> </div>
                                    </div>
                                  
                                    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="pw">Password</label>
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pw" name="password" placeholder="password" maxlength="10">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                        <div class="text-right">
                                            <button id="submit" class="btn btn-secondary"><a href="UserHome.jsp" style="text-decoration:none">Cancel</a></button>

                                            <a href=\"UpdateProfile?action=getEditCustomer&id=" + c.getId() + "\">
                                                <input type="submit"  id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"value="Update"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>


                </div>
            </div>

    </body>

[UpdateProfileServlet.java]
/*
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Licenses/license-default.txt to change this license
 * Click nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Class.java to edit this template
 */
package servlet;

import ict.Bean.AccountBean;
import ict.db.AccountDB;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author plksa
 */
@WebServlet(name = "UpdateProfileServlet", urlPatterns = {"/UpdateProfileServlet"})
public class UpdateProfileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.print(request.getAttributeNames());
            String id = request.getParameter("id");
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            String password = request.getParameter("pw");
            String role = request.getParameter("role");
//            String day = request.getParameter("day");
//            String month = request.getParameter("month");
//            String year = request.getParameter("year");
//            String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
//            String dateOfBirth = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

            // Database connection details
            //String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/system_db";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/asm_gp13_db_final";
            String username = "root";
            String dbPassword = "";

            //AccountDB db = new AccountDB("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/system_db", "root", "");
            AccountDB db = new AccountDB(url, username,dbPassword);
            AccountBean account = new AccountBean();
            account.setId(id);
            account.setUsername(name);
            account.setEmail(email);
            account.setPassword(password);
            account.setRole(role);
            
            
            //boolean updateSuccess = db.updateUser(id, name, email, password, role, dateOfBirth, gender);
            boolean updateSuccess = false;
        try {
            updateSuccess = db.updateUser(name, email, password);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UpdateProfileServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

            if (updateSuccess) {
                if ("user".equals(role)) {
                    response.sendRedirect("UserHome.jsp"); // Redirect to homepage
                } else if ("courier".equals(role)) {
                    response.sendRedirect("CourHome.jsp"); // Redirect to homepage
                } else if ("Technician(Administrator)".equals(role)) {
                    response.sendRedirect("TechHome.jsp"); // Redirect to homepage
                }
            } else {
                request.setAttribute("errorMessage", "Failed to update account.");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("update.jsp").forward(request, response); // Send back to the form with an error message
            }
    }

}

[AccountDB.java]
https://pastebin.com/mjcdJVMS
I was trying to update the profile in the database, but I tried tons of ways for it and it still have error.

looks like the password is null, you have done an empty check, see if that object is null.

It looks like the password is null and when method isEmpty() is called it will throw NullPointerException.  you add a condition in the class UpdateProfileServlet.doPost before try catch block
if(password == null){
 password = "";
}


the password should be able to be empty, but when the password is empty, the original password is applied when the button is clicked
because that is only for inserting "new password" if the user wants to change the password.

When the password field is empty it doesn't pass it in the request. so in the backend password is null.
